# Display All .MP3 Files From A Folder In An Audio Tag

Tags: php, html, audio

How can I get all audio files from a folder and display it in Audio Tags?

What I Have Tried

```
$sPath = 'music/favorite/*.mp3';

foreach (glob($sPath) AS $mp3) {
    print $mp3 . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: It helps to explain why this code didn't do what you expected it to do (i.e. what it actually did that you didn't expect).

Comment: what does ` Audio Tags` mean?

Comment: @PrabhSingh, fix your Answer acceptance rate. Why should anyone help you in future when you don't give feedback? You type a lot for free expertise but suddenly it's hard for you to give "thanks" (click "upvote" arrow or click "correct" tick) in your other questions.

Comment: @VC.One My bad, I will start saying thanks from now on. =D

Comment: @PrabhSingh, Don't say it, just show it -- by accepting/upvoting any useful Answers you get in future. Now onto your Question...

Comment: Your question is confusing. You use "Audio Tags" (with capitals) like it's a title/name of a software. Is that correct? Is it a desktop tool or some PHP api code? I can't see how your shown PHP code is talking to this Audio Tags thing. Is your real question this :  _"Using PHP, how can I generate automatic **HTML5 audio tags** for each mp3 file in a folder?"_ ... **OR** do you mean.. _"How to display any existing tags of mp3 files from a specific folder using PHP?"_ here tags means mp3 metadata (artists, title, etc) stored in tags within a file.

Comment: @VC.One Audio tag as in <audio controls> <source src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg"> <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser does not support the audio tag. </audio>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it inside of the `foreach`. If you just want to `echo` the files, just do it like this:

```
foreach (glob($sPath) AS $mp3) {
    echo '<audio>';
        echo '<source src="'.$mp3.'" type="audio/mpeg">';
    echo '</audio>';
}
```

Maybe you need to adjust the path of your `$mp3` var.

*It's just a sample. Please don't blame me because I didn't tested this.*

Hope this helps.